# Aggregating date in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a purpose of reporting I need to present data from table:

```
table A (column1, column2, date1, date2, date3,...,dateN)
```

My query need to present all dates in one column separated with # .

```
(YYYY-MM-DD# YYYY-MM-DD#..)
```

But problem is that number of date columns is not fixed, because from product to product can be different number of dates.

Any idea ?

Comment: show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: You need to show the source which genertaed `date1,date2,..,dateN` we might have to alter that query

Comment: what you mean product have different number of dates? tableA is a dynamic view?

Comment: Once a table is created, the "number of date columns" in a table *is* fixed, or, it's the same for every row in the table.  Could you possibly have meant to say "not all the date columns are populated" in every row?

Comment: anyway, just concatenate all column in a dynamic query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement works for postgresql, but you can replace the `||` with `+` for sql-server I think, just try and it should work, you should be able to figure out the rest.

`||` is the concatenation symbol in postgres or you could also use the concatenation function available.

`SELECT column1 || CASE WHEN column2 IS NOT NULL THEN '#' || column2 ELSE '' END || ... FROM tablehere`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

After consideration, I want to change my answer.  Perhaps a little lighter

```
Declare @YourTable table (Column1 int,Column2 int,date1 date,date2 date,date3 date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,25,'2016-01-15','2016-03-22',null),
(2,50,'2016-04-15','2016-07-29','2016-09-30')

Select Column1
      ,Column2
      ,Dates=Replace(Replace((
             Select  x=format(date1,'yyyy-MM-dd# ')
                    ,x=format(date2,'yyyy-MM-dd# ')
                    ,x=format(date3,'yyyy-MM-dd# ')
                    --x=format(dateNN,'yyyy-MM-dd# ')
              For  XML Path('')
             ) ,'<x>',''),'</x>','')
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Column1 Column2 Dates
1       25      2016-01-15# 2016-03-22# 
2       50      2016-04-15# 2016-07-29# 2016-09-30#
```

Comment: The output is still wrong, you still have a # at the end which should not be there.

Comment: @RaulCuth Not according to my understanding of the requirements

Comment: Yes, it could be so, but the user stated that: My query need to present all dates in one column separated with # .

Comment: Doesn't matter that much really it can be modified for this situation also, its a neat answer anyway, a bit too complicated, but nice nonetheless.